# Multi dimentional array validator

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following two arrays one array contains all valid fields and 2nd array is the data array which i want to parse.I wanted to remove any invalid fields in the data array that doesn't map with the valid field array:

Valid Fields array:

```
$valid_fields = array(
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "uid",
    "email",
    "address" => array(
        "mailing" => array("building_no", "street", "city", "zip", "country"),
        "billing" => array("building_no", "street", "city", "zip", "country"),
        "home" => array("building_no", "street", "city", "zip", "country"),
        "work" => array("building_no", "street", "city", "zip", "country")
    ),
    "home_address",
    "home_address",
    "billing_address",
    "dob",
    "gender",
    "occupation",
    "ip",
    "site_id",
    "date_created",
    "social_network_ids" => array("facebook",
        "twitter",
        "pintreast",
        "myspace",
        "skype"),
    "occupations" => array("current", "past" => array()),
    "education", "income", "country", "city", "longitude", "latitude");
```

Data array:

```
$data = array(
    "first_name" => "FFF",
    "last_name" => "LLL",
    "uid" => "12345", "email" => "aaa@f.com",
    "address" => array(
        "mailing" => array("building_no" => "BBAA", "street" => "BBSS", "city" => "BBCC")
    ),
    "social_network_ids" => array(
        "facebook" => "fbid",
        "twitter" => "twitter",
    ),
    "occupations" => array("current", "past" => array(), "yolo" => "tttt"),
);
```

my parsing function:

```
function parse_array($parms, $valid_fields) {

    $result = array();
    foreach ($valid_fields as $valid_field) {

        if (is_array($parms[$valid_field])) {
            $result[$valid_field] = parse_array($parms[$valid_field], $valid_field);
        } else {
            if (isset($parms[$valid_field]) && $parms[$valid_field] != "") {
                $result[$valid_field] = $parms[$valid_field];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and i call it it gives me this array which obviously not valid:

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => FFF
    [last_name] => LLL
    [uid] => 12345
    [email] => aaa@f.com
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP function you're using $valid_field as an index to get the item from the $data array, but sometimes $valid_field can be an array itself, try this approach:

```
function parse_array($parms, $valid_fields) {
$result = array();
foreach ($valid_fields as $k => $valid_field) {
    $key = $valid_field;
    if (is_array($valid_field)) {
        $key = $k;
    }
    if (isset($parms[$key])) {
        if (is_array($parms[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = parse_array($parms[$key], $valid_field);
        } else {
            if (isset($parms[$key]) && $parms[$valid_field] != "") {
                $result[$key] = $parms[$valid_field];
            }
        }
    }
}
return $result;
}
```

Comment: @KaraneBird Yea great it works i just receive too many warnings of undefined index a way i can actually handle that thing?

Comment: using `isset($parms[$key])` before `if(is_array($parms[$key]))` will work i guess ?

Comment: @KaraneBird Thanks alot mate i don't know why people marked this question as unable to understand and down voted. I Marked your answer as right one :)

Comment: Haters gonna hate, what to do? lol thanks.